# json2csharp generated class causing webservice call to fail

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

The following function call using json.net to retrieve my data is causing it to break I dont beleive its the length of data as the function works fine for other data it may be down to my class layout. Even if i change it to MovieList object it also bombs out any ideas.

Class Generated from  http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class MovieList
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string secondry_images { get; set; }
    public string actor { get; set; }
    public string actoress { get; set; }
    public string director { get; set; }
    public string music_director { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string age_restriction { get; set; }
    public string box_office { get; set; }
    public string official_site { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string writers { get; set; }
    public int imdb { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
    public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
    public string videous { get; set; }
    public string videos { get; set; }
    public string comming_soon { get; set; }
    public string avg { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
 {
    public List<MovieList> movie_list { get; set; }
 }
```

I am calling the function as such

```
public async Task<List<RootObject>> GetAllMovies()
{
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "list_of_movie");
        var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonresult);


         return jarray;
}
```

I then call this on the following method of my listview.

```
private async void grdMovies_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
   List<RootObject> movieList = await popcorn_dal.GetAllMovies();
   var listView = (ListView)sender;
   listView.ItemsSource = movieList;

}
```

But the debugger bombs out giving the following error.
 [image]

Can someone help with class defination please.

> {"movie_list":[{"id":"76","name":"Bajrangi Bhaijaan","description":"Bajrangi Bhaijaan is an upcoming Indian drama film directed by Kabir Khan, and produced by Salman Khan and Rockline Venkatesh. It features Salman Khan, Kareena Kapoor Khan and Nawazuddin Siddiqui in lead roles.Principal photography began in New Delhi in November 2014, and the film is scheduled for a worldwide release on 17 July 2015, which is Eid celeberation time.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/1434357192.png","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Salman Khan","actoress":"Kareena Kapoor","director":"Kabir Khan","music_director":"Pritam Chakraborty","release_date":"July 17, 2015","tags":"Drama, Action","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"0","official_site":"http://bajrangibhaijaanmovie.in/","duration":"163","writers":"Kabir Khan","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"Hindi","created":"2015-07-02 09:30:20","modified":"2015-07-21 14:09:12","movie_category_id":"2,4","slug":"BajrangiBhaijaan","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"4"},{"id":"78","name":"Karachi Se Lahore","description":"Karachi se Lahore is an upcoming Pakistani comedy road film directed and produced by Wajahat Rauf under production banner Showcase Productions. The film's story is written by Yasir Hussain. Karachi se Lahore, featuring an ensemble cast including Javed Sheikh, Mantaha Tareen Maqsood, Yasir Hussain, Ahmed Ali, Eshita Syed, Aashir Wajahat and Rasheed Naz, whereas lead roles are played by Shehzad Sheikh and Ayesha Omer.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/1430737156.png","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Javed Sheikh","actoress":"Ayesha Omer","director":"Wajahat Rauf","music_director":"Sur Darwaish","release_date":"July 31, 2015","tags":"Comedy, Family","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"40","official_site":"","duration":"","writers":"Yasir Hussain","imdb":9,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-07-02 09:44:25","modified":"2015-07-31 15:21:16","movie_category_id":"13","slug":"KarachiSeLahore","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"82","name":"Wrong No.","description":"Wrong No. (also written as Wrong Number) is an upcoming Pakistani romantic comedy film directed by Yasir Nawaz and co-produced by Yasir Nawaz, Nida Yasir and Hassan Zia under the production banner YNH Films.The film features Javed Sheikh, Danish Taimoor, Nadeem Jaffri, Danish Nawaz, Shafqat Cheema, Sohai Ali Abro and Janita Asma in lead roles.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Wrong_No._film.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Danish Taimoor","actoress":"Janita Asma","director":"Yasir Nawaz","music_director":"Waqar Ali","release_date":"July 3, 2015","tags":"Romance, Drama","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"0","official_site":"","duration":"0","writers":"","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-07-03 08:46:17","modified":"2015-07-04 09:05:35","movie_category_id":"4,16","slug":"WrongNo.","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"4"},{"id":"87","name":"Minions","description":"Minions is a 2015 American 3D computer-animated family comedy film, and a prequel/spin-off to the Despicable Me franchise. Produced by Illumination Entertainment for Universal Pictures, the film was written by Brian Lynch, directed by Pierre Coffin and Kyle Balda, and produced by Chris Meledandri and Janet Healy. The film stars Pierre Coffin (as the Minions), Sandra Bullock, Jon Hamm, Michael Keaton, Allison Janney, Steve Coogan, and Geoffrey Rush.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Minions_poster.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Sandra Bullock, Jon Hamm, Michael Keaton","actoress":"","director":"Pierre Coffin, Kyle Balda","music_director":"Heitor Pereira","release_date":"July 10, 2015","tags":"Animation, Comedy, Family","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"148","official_site":"http://www.minionsmovie.com/?redirect=off","duration":"91","writers":"Brian Lynch","imdb":7,"status":"1","language":"Engliish","created":"2015-07-10 16:19:44","modified":"2015-07-10 16:19:44","movie_category_id":"13,15,17","slug":"Minions","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"5"},{"id":"91","name":"Bin Roye","description":"Bin Roye is an upcoming Pakistani romantic drama film directed by Momina Duraid, Shahzad Kashmiri, one of the movie song is directed by Haissam Hussain, produced by Momina Duraid, starring Mahira Khan, Humayun Saeed, Armeena Rana Khan, Zeba Bakhtiar, Javed Sheikh and others.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Bin_Roye_film.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Mahira Khan, Humayun Saeed","actoress":"Armeena Rana Khan","director":"Shehzad Kashmiri, Momina Duraid","music_director":"","release_date":"July 18, 2015","tags":"Drama, Romance","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"21","official_site":"","duration":"150","writers":"Farhat Ishtiaq","imdb":7,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-07-17 17:42:05","modified":"2015-07-17 17:42:05","movie_category_id":"4,16","slug":"BinRoye","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"2"},{"id":"94","name":"Brothers","description":"Brothers is an upcoming Indian Martial Arts action-drama film, directed by Karan Malhotra and produced by Dharma Productions, Lionsgate Films and Endemol India. The film is an official remake of the 2011 Hollywood film Warrior. It stars Akshay Kumar, Sidharth Malhotra and Jacqueline Fernandez in lead roles, while Jackie Shroff will play a supporting role.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/1435305741.png","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Akshay Kumar, Jackie Shroff, Sidharth Malhotra","actoress":"","director":"Karan Malhotra","music_director":"Ajay Atul","release_date":"August 14, 2015","tags":"Drama, Sport","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"0","official_site":"","duration":"","writers":"Siddharth Garima","imdb":0,"status":"1","language":"Hindi","created":"2015-07-18 08:12:26","modified":"2015-08-17 18:44:02","movie_category_id":"4","slug":"Brothers","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"104","name":"Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation","description":"Mission: Impossible – Rogue Nation is a 2015 American action spy film written and directed by Christopher McQuarrie. It is the fifth installment in the Mission: Impossible series and was preceded by Mission: Impossible – Ghost Protocol (2011). It stars Tom Cruise, who reprises his role as IMF Agent Ethan Hunt. It is produced by Cruise, J. J. Abrams, and David Ellison of Skydance Productions.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Mission_Impossible_Rogue_Nation_poster.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Tom Cruise","actoress":"Rebecca Ferguson","director":"Christopher McQuarrie","music_director":"Joe Kraemer","release_date":"July 31, 2015","tags":"Action, Adventure, Thriller","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"40","official_site":"http://www.missionimpossible.com/","duration":"131","writers":"Christopher McQuarrie","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"English","created":"2015-07-31 14:58:16","modified":"2015-07-31 17:27:40","movie_category_id":"2,5,12","slug":"MissionImpossibleRogueNation","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"3"},{"id":"106","name":"Dekh Magar Pyaar Say","description":"Dekh Magar Pyaar Say is a 2015 Pakistani romantic comedy film directed by Asad ul Haq and produced by Ali Murtaza under the production banner Shiny Toy Guns. The film will be the directorial debut for Haq. The movie will star Humaima Malick and Sikander Rizvi in the lead roles. The movie will also be the acting debut for its male lead Sikander Rizvi.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/DMPS_Teaser_Poster_1.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Amna Ilyas, Irfan Khoosat, Humaima Malik","actoress":"","director":"Asad Ul Haq","music_director":"","release_date":"August 14, 2015","tags":"Comedy, Romance","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"18","official_site":"","duration":"","writers":"Saba Imtiaz","imdb":5,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-08-17 18:39:45","modified":"2015-08-17 18:39:45","movie_category_id":"16,17","slug":"DekhMagarPyaarSay","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"107","name":"Shah","description":"Shah is a 2015 Pakistani biographical sports film directed and written by Adnan Sarwar. The film is produced under banner Logos Film. The film is based on the life of boxer Hussain Shah who won the bronze medal at 1988 Summer Olympics and became the only boxer in Pakistan's history to secure an Olympic medal in that sport. The film stars Adnan Sarwar in lead to portray the role of Hussain Shah in the film after undergoing a year boxing training programme. The film cast also features Kiran Chaudhary, Sardar Baloch, Adeel Raees and Gulab Chandio.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Shah.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Sardar Baloch, Gulab Chandio, Kiran Chaudhry","actoress":"","director":"Adnan Sarwar","music_director":"Adnan Sarwar, Farhan Albert","release_date":"August 13, 2015","tags":"Biography, Sport ","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"10","official_site":"","duration":"","writers":"Adnan Sarwar","imdb":9,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-08-17 18:55:38","modified":"2015-08-17 18:55:38","movie_category_id":"4","slug":"Shah","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"108","name":"Moor","description":"Moor (Urdu‎) is a 2015 Pakistani drama film directed, written by Jami and produced by Nadeem Mandviwalla under production banner Azad Film Company. The film stars Hameed Sheikh in lead along with Samiya Mumtaz, Shaz Khan, Nayyar Ejaz, Ayaz Samoo and Abdul Qadir in lead roles. The film's title, Moor, is a Pashto word meaning "Mother". Moor was previously named as Morqaye.(maan sahiba) Film's story depicts the railway system of Balochistan, especially the closure of Zhob valley railways in 1984. Besides the movie shows how families are run by the women. According to the director of the movie, the film depicts living through the problems faced by Pakistan.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/Moor_(film).jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Hameed Sheikh","actoress":"","director":"Jami","music_director":"Strings","release_date":"August 14, 2015","tags":"Drama","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"10","official_site":"","duration":"150","writers":"Jami, Nazira Ali, Eman Syed","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"Urdu","created":"2015-08-17 19:02:34","modified":"2015-08-17 19:02:34","movie_category_id":"4","slug":"Moor","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"109","name":"The Man from U.N.C.L.E.","description":"The Man from U.N.C.L.E. is an action comedy spy film directed by Guy Ritchie and co-written by Lionel Wigram and Ritchie, based on the 1964 MGM television series of the same name, which was created by Sam Rolfe. The film stars Henry Cavill, Armie Hammer, Alicia Vikander, Elizabeth Debicki and Hugh Grant.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/The_Man_from_U.N.C.L.E._poster.jpg","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Henry Cavill","actoress":"","director":"Guy Ritchie","music_director":"Daniel Pemberton","release_date":"August 7, 2015","tags":"Action, Adventure, Comedy","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"14","official_site":"http://www.manfromuncle.com/","duration":"116","writers":"Guy Ritchie, Lionel Wigram","imdb":8,"status":"1","language":"English","created":"2015-08-17 19:09:30","modified":"2015-08-17 19:16:48","movie_category_id":"2,12,17","slug":"TheManfromU.N.C.L.E.","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"110","name":"All Is Well","description":"All Is Well is a 2015 Bollywood family drama film directed by Umesh Shukla and produced by Bhushan Kumar, Krishan Kumar, Shyam Bajaj and Varun Bajaj and co-produced by Ajay Kapoor. It stars Abhishek Bachchan, Rishi Kapoor, Asin and Supriya Pathak in lead roles.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/1438590260.png","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":"Rishi Kapoor","actoress":"Asin","director":"Umesh Shukla","music_director":"Himesh Reshammiya, Amaal Mallik, Meet Bros Anjjan, Mithoon","release_date":"August 21, 2015","tags":"Comedy, Drama, Romance","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"10","official_site":"","duration":"126","writers":"Sumit Arora, Niren Bhatt","imdb":5,"status":"1","language":"Hindi","created":"2015-08-21 21:34:23","modified":"2015-08-21 21:34:23","movie_category_id":"4,16,17","slug":"AllIsWell","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"},{"id":"111","name":"Fantastic Four","description":"Fantastic Four (stylized as Fant4stic) is a 2015 superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name. It is the third theatrical Fantastic Four film to be distributed by 20th Century Fox, and a reboot of the Fantastic Four film franchise. Directed by Josh Trank, with a screenplay by Jeremy Slater, Simon Kinberg and Trank, the film stars Miles Teller, Michael B. Jordan, Kate Mara, Jamie Bell, Toby Kebbell, Reg E. Cathey, and Tim Blake Nelson. In Fantastic Four, the team must learn to harness abilities gained from an alternate universe to save Earth from a friend turned enemy.\r\n","image":"http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/1438839970.png","secondry_images":"Movie/","actor":" Miles Teller, Kate Mara, Michael B. Jordan","actoress":"","director":"Josh Trank","music_director":"Marco Beltrami, Philip Glass","release_date":"August 4, 2015","tags":"Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi ","age_restriction":"13","box_office":"105","official_site":"http://www.fantasticfourmovie.com/","duration":"100","writers":"Jeremy Slater, Simon Kinberg","imdb":4,"status":"1","language":"English","created":"2015-08-21 22:04:22","modified":"2015-08-21 22:04:22","movie_category_id":"2,12","slug":"FantasticFour","movie_show_time_id":"0","theatre_movie_screen_id":"0","videous":"","videos":"","comming_soon":"0","avg":"0"}]}

**Edit Note**

I changed the function to the below but its still bombing out when I try to send it to mylsitview using the loaded method

```
    public async Task<RootObject> GetAllMovies()
    {
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "list_of_movie");
         jsonresult=jsonresult.Replace("\"", "\\u022");
        var jarray  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonresult);


        return jarray;
    }
```

My Xaml For My Listview which is in a hubcontrol so I dont no why it is is bombing out now as the json is indeaded being passed correctly

```
       <HubSection x:Name="listMovies" x:Uid="HubSection2" Header="SECTION 2" Width="Auto"
                         DataContext="{Binding Groups[0]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemClick="GroupSection_ItemClick"
                        Loaded="listMovies_Loaded"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
Then i use the loaded command below to try and load the data into the listview.

    private async void listMovies_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



           popcornpk_Dal popcorn_dal = new popcornpk_Dal();

          MovieDetail _movieDetails = await popcorn_dal.GetMovieDetails(2);
            string _mycount = _movieDetails.movie_details.description;

     //       List<City> myCity= await popcorn_dal.GetCityListAsync();
//
            RootObject movieList = await popcorn_dal.GetAllMovies();
            var listView = (ListView)sender;

            listView.ItemsSource = movieList;

        }
```

Comment: the json is a list of movies of course its a list how but how do i make a list of MoviesList so ican access its data correctly

Comment: If you have more question, please ask a new question. Also, you can't just  simply replace all `"` by `\\u022`, it will mess up the whole data.

Comment: Unless you HAVE TO USE WCF you are making life extremely difficult for yourself. WCF is legacy technology and definitely not recommended for modern JSON web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json is not a list, an object containing a list. Just use

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonresult);
```

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk, A list should start with `[` char. your json starts with `{` . So it is a single object. Your list is `obj.movie_list`

Comment: please see notes above its stil bombing out so it is.

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk 1) don't play with the json like `jsonresult=jsonresult.Replace("\"", "\\u022");` if it is invalid there isn't anything you can do about it. 2) If your question is how to fix an invalid json string, I repeat it again you can't do anything about it. Ask the json provider to fix it.

Comment: no it is stil bracking and not passing the list in dont no why still that debugging error

Comment: it is bracking on this line when i try to pass the data to the listview 

    var listView = (ListView)sender;
//
          listView.ItemsSource = movieList;

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk Your json posted in question is invalid. The property starts with `"description": "Moor (Urdu‎) is a 2015 Pakistani ......` has an invalid string `"Mother"` which should be `\"Mother\"`. If the json in your question is excatly the same string from your API, then you have no luck. Ask them to fix it. You may send them [this link](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @windowsphoneexpertuk BTW: Referring to my answer, I hope you don't set `listView.ItemsSource=obj`, as I mentioned before it should be `listView.ItemsSource=obj.movie_list`

Comment: Brilliant thanks also btw the data loads a bit slow is their anyway of caching it using this method ?

Answer (score 1):

You should deserialize it into a `RootObject`, not a `List<RootObject>` :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Note: the json seems to be invalid. On the 10th Movie' description contains unescaped double quotes `"` :

> "name":"Moor",
>
> "description":"Moor (Urdu‎) is a 2015 Pakistani drama
> film directed, written by Jami and produced by Nadeem Mandviwalla
> under production banner Azad Film Company. The film stars Hameed
> Sheikh in lead along with Samiya Mumtaz, Shaz Khan, Nayyar Ejaz, Ayaz
> Samoo and Abdul Qadir in lead roles. The film's title, Moor, is a
> Pashto word meaning **"Mother"**. Moor was previously named as
> Morqaye.(maan sahiba) Film's story depicts the railway system of
> Balochistan, especially the closure of Zhob valley railways in 1984.
> Besides the movie shows how families are run by the women. According
> to the director of the movie, the film depicts living through the
> problems faced by Pakistan.\r\n"

Comment: what is the best way to cleanse the data using c# any advise their

Comment: There isn't really an appropriate way of cleansing an invalid json, other than doing it by hand.

Comment: please see notes above its stil bombing out so it is.

Comment: this data works fine in the andiord and ios apps though

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonresult);
```

And then

```
jarray.movie_list
```

will be your List.

Comment: Btw, MovieList is a bad name for that class because it does not represent a list, but a single item. Use something like Movie, MovieInfo, MovieListEntry, etc.